# Call Controller Method using Ajax request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

please your help to call a method from controller using ajax request, below is my code, but error had returned says that the source of controller cannot be found.

here is my ajax code

```
 function GetServices() {
    var e = document.getElementById("catagories");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var id = e.options[e.selectedIndex].id;

$.ajax({
    url: "~/VasController/ExecuteVas/",
    //url: '<%= Url.Action("GetServices", "Vas") %>',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {"id": id},
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});

}
```

and here is my controller method

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string GetServices(string id)
        {
            return id;

        }
```

kindly advice, i am still beginner in c# and MVC

Comment: You are asking about `MVC`, but showing a `WebMethod` example! Also, your `uri` is not correct in javascript code.

Comment: how can i correct the url in javascript code ? discard the web methode i am using MVC

Comment: What was wrong with this one `<%= Url.Action("GetServices", "Vas") %>`? Mark the method GetServices() with `[HttpGet]`. That should do it.

Comment: this way return an error message with the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Your uri would be (when using pure MVC), "/Controller/Action" (remove ~)

Comment: i have try this, but still i have error

Comment: This is right time you start debugging the application. Put a breakpoint in your controller action. If the system fails even before reaching there, put a breakpoint in Application_Error() in Global.asax

Answer (score 0):

in your controller file

```
public class YourControllerNameController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Dosomething(int? id)
   {
    //your code
    return View();
   }
}
```

then in your view

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Dosomething","YourControllerName")', { id: id }, function (data) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following:
1- Decorate the Action method with `[HttpPost]` tag
2- Remove the word 'controller' for the Ajax URL it would be `'url: "~/Vas/ExecuteVas/"`
3- if 1 and 2 did not work,Try putting the Ajax URL without `~/`